# Powershell shortcut permissions using ACL?

Tags: powershell, permissions, acl, shortcut

I have an MSI that is pushed through Intune and installed on users' computers. This MSI is basically a flash browser needed for a specific webapp. What i need to do is to create a custom shortcut and input a url in the target of the shortcut forcing the browser to that website (because the browser does not have a place to enter a URL).

I have no issues creating the shortcut, however i want to make sure that a user can't go in and modify the target by right-clicking the shortcut and changing the URL parameter allowing them to browse google or facebook or whatever through this browser.

this is what i currently have for the shortcut:

```
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject ("WScript.Shell")

$ShortCut = $Shell.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Browser - PROD.lnk")

$ShortCut.TargetPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\CompanyBrowser.exe"

$ShortCut.Arguments='-URL "https://company.url"'

$ShortCut.Save()
```

I popped the shortcut onto the public desktop so that standard users could not modify it, however some of these users are local admins on their machine. What i was hoping was to change the security tab in the properties of the shortcut to allow the local administrator account only access to read/execute, but not modify this shortcut.

I am playing around with ACL function , but it seems that it's all or nothing and when i run the following script, it completely blocks the shortcut from even being executed

```
$ProdACL = Get-Acl -Path "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Browser - PROD.lnk"
$identity = "BUILTIN\Administrators"
$fileSystemRights = "Modify"
$type = "Deny"
$fileSystemAccessRuleArgumentList = $identity, $fileSystemRights, $type
$fileSystemAccessRule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $fileSystemAccessRuleArgumentList
$ProdACL.SetAccessRule($fileSystemAccessRule)
Set-Acl -Path "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Browser - PROD.lnk" -AclObject $ProdACL
```

I'm no powershell expert but i believe i am close and perhaps not using the right parameters with ACL.

any help would be MUCH appreciated.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that modify includes read/execute and deny takes precedence over allow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Doug Maurer is right.

You need to remove the inheritance first by preserving rules :

```
$ProdACL = Get-Acl -Path "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Browser - PROD.lnk"
$ProdACL.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $true)
Set-Acl -Path "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Browser - PROD.lnk" -AclObject $ProdACL
```

The first `$True` for the `SetAccessRuleProtection` method is blocking inheritance (`$False` to inherit) and the second is to copy the inherited rules (`$False` to clear inherited rules). The second value is ignored if the first one is set to `$False`.

Then, remove the rule that give Administrators the FullControl :

```
$ProdACL = Get-Acl -Path "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Browser - PROD.lnk"
$identity = "BUILTIN\Administrators"
$fileSystemRights = "FullControl"
$type = "Allow"
$fileSystemAccessRuleArgumentList = $identity, $fileSystemRights, $type
$fileSystemAccessRule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $fileSystemAccessRuleArgumentList
$ProdACL.RemoveAccessRule($fileSystemAccessRule)
Set-Acl -Path "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Browser - PROD.lnk" -AclObject $ProdACL
```

Notice that you have to get the ACL again once you had setted it to block inheritance.

I have copied your code, but it can be simplified as this (with inheritance blocking here) :

```
#Block Inheritance
$ProdACL = Get-Acl -Path "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Browser - PROD.lnk"
$ProdACL.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $true)
Set-Acl -Path "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Browser - PROD.lnk" -AclObject $ProdACL

# Set new ACL
$ProdACL = Get-Acl -Path "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Browser - PROD.lnk"
$identity = "BUILTIN\Administrators"
$fileSystemAccessRule = $ProdACL.Access | Where IdentityReference -eq $identity
$ProdACL.RemoveAccessRule($fileSystemAccessRule)
Set-Acl -Path "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Browser - PROD.lnk" -AclObject $ProdACL
```